# Add class to a div which previously had a active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add the `class="demo"` to the

```
<div class="single-step active">
```

Which previously had the `class="active"`

On the click of next button with `id="sf-next"`

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guggu2007/1oouthL4/)

This is what i have used till now.

```
$("#sf-next").click(function() {
     $(".active").addClass("done");
});
```

But when I click next, `class="active"` moves to the second div and so does the `class="done"`.

But this should not be the case. `Class="done"` should be added to the div which previously had the `class="active"`.

Comment: Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and remove extra stuff from your fiddle to help with getting good answers.

Comment: Use jquery [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)  function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its really a next button you can apply the new class instead of the actual "active" to the prev active

```
$("#sf-next").click(function() {
 $(".active").prev().addClass("done");
});
```

Otherwise you have to find out the point where the active class changed and execute your onclick function before this point.

Comment: you are awesome man, thanks a lot...                                            had no idea about prev()

Answer (score 0):

it's quit simple buddy. just give the div an id like `myDivId`. then create a function like bellow:

```js
function myfunction(){document.getElementById("myDivId").setAttribute("class","demo");}
```

next thing you shoud do is to add an `onclick=myfunction()` to button. simple like that

Answer (score 0):

Now this will be happening beacuse there is some other javascript which is adding the class active to it. So what you have to do is either of the 2 things 
1) Modify the same method that is adding the class active to add it to the same element rather than doing to the next element and at the same time add the done class too.
2) Before that method is getting called add class 'done' to class 'active' and after that method is called add 'active' to 'done'.

If you can add that method which is adding active I will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug your html.
But the possible solutions are:

1.Either make the div you want to add class as the parent of your button and  then use

```
$("#sf-next").click(function() {
 $(this).parent().addClass("done");
});
```

2. Or if you putting both the button and div in the same parent div, use this:

```
$("#sf-next").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.active').addClass("done");   
});
```

In both cases i am getting the current object of the div. Hope you got my point. Happy coding.